# How to put pgf preamble into an mplstyle style

Tags: python, matplotlib

An example of matplotlibs pgf backaend with latex is [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/userdemo/pgf_preamble_sgskip.html). Since I use it often, I would like to create a matplotlib style from this. Unfortunately we have to specify all the latex packages in the pgf.preamble as indicated [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593261/how-to-avoid-calling-latex-in-matplotlib-output-to-pgf). For some reason the pgf.preamble option does not get updated from the style I created. How can I use it in a matplotlib style?

The style I have created:

```
~/.config/matplotlib/stylelib $ cat pgf_debug.mplstyle | egrep -v "^[ \t]*[#]" | egrep -v "^[ \t]*$"
font.family         : serif
text.usetex         : True  ## use latex for all text handling. The following fonts
axes.grid           : True   ## display grid or not
                                          ## Note the use of string escapes here ('1f77b4', instead of 1f77b4)
axes.xmargin        : 0  ## x margin.  See `axes.Axes.margins`
axes.ymargin        : 0  ## y margin See `axes.Axes.margins`
savefig.bbox        : tight     ## 'tight' or 'standard'.
savefig.pad_inches  : 0      ## Padding to be used when bbox is set to 'tight'
pgf.rcfonts : False
pgf.preamble :  [ "\\usepackage{siunitx}" ]
```

The code I use it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

print("\n".join(plt.style.available)) # My style is there!
mpl.use("pgf")
plt.style.use("pgf_debug")
x = np.linspace(0,1,num=50)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,x)
ax.text(0.6,0.1,r"foo \SI{1}{\volt}")
fig.savefig("mplstyle_mwe.png")
```

The error message indicates that the siunitx package is not loaded:

```
ValueError: Error processing 'foo \SI{1}{\volt}'
LaTeX Output:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...0000}{12.000000}\selectfont foo \SI
                                                  {1}{\volt }
<*> ...0}{12.000000}\selectfont foo \SI{1}{\volt}}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

On the other hand, siunitx is loaded and the correct figure is generated if I load the properties with pyplots's rcParam.update() function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

mpl.use("pgf")
x = np.linspace(0,1,num=50)

plt.rcParams.update({
    "font.family": "serif",  # use serif/main font for text elements
    "text.usetex": True,     # use inline math for ticks
    "pgf.rcfonts": False,    # don't setup fonts from rc parameters
    "pgf.preamble": [
        "\\usepackage{siunitx}",          # load additional packages
        "\\usepackage{unicode-math}",   # unicode math setup
        r"\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}",
        r"\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}",  # serif font via preamble
        ]
})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,x)
ax.text(0.6,0.1,r"foo \SI{1}{\volt}")
fig.savefig("mplstyle_mwe2.png")
```

What am I doing wrong, and how could I use the style for pgf plots? 
I bonus question might be whether mpl.use("pgf") could be added to the style?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I realised the way to make it work was to follow the advice given in "ChowlandGFD"'s answer, but to remove the comma seperating the seperate inputs.
In other words, replace:

```
pgf.preamble: \usepackage{siunitx}, \usepackage{mhchem}
```

with:

```
pgf.preamble: \usepackage{siunitx} \usepackage{mhchem}
```

in the mplstyle file.

I determined this by comparing what the mplstyle file had set for `rcParams['pgf.preamble']` with the equivalent value when setting the parameter via the command
`rcParams.update({'pgf.preamble': r'\usepackage{siunitx} \usepackage{mhchem}'})`.

Note that pgf.preamble does not require a python list, and can use a string for multiple package imports.

Note also that this was tested with the following preceeding mplstyle commands:

```
font.family: sans-serif
text.usetex: True
pgf.rcfonts: False
pgf.texsystem: lualatex
```

and with `mpl.use("pgf")`; though not in the style file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this today when I came across the same problem. I think the key is that matplotlib doesn't want formatted strings in the style file (e.g. compare the `font.family: serif` entries in the above examples).
The following style file should correctly load all the packages you want in the last example:

```
font.family: serif

text.usetex: True

pgf.rcfonts: False
pgf.preamble: \usepackage{siunitx}, \usepackage{unicode-math}, \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}, \setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
```

I haven't managed to solve your bonus question, but at least the only setup needed now is `mpl.use("pgf")` and `plt.style.use("mystyle")`

Comment: For me, the comma separated value list doesn't work. I can do `pgf.preamble: \usepackage{siunitx}` but `pgf.preamble: \usepackage{siunitx}, \usepackage{mhchem}` fails with a lualatex compilation error